# форма не передает параметр

Tags: html, вёрстка

первых 3 радио передают только 1 в чем проблема что то я совсем не пойму.

```html
<!-- /.box-header -->
<!-- form start -->
<form action="javascript:insert()" method="get">
  <div class="box-body">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Выбор года</label>
      <div class="radio">
        <label>
<input type="radio" name="Radios_god" id="Radios_god" value="1" >2017_2018         </label>
      </div>
      <div class="radio">
        <label>
<input type="radio" name="Radios_god" id="Radios_god" value="2" >2018_2019       </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Выбор тематики</label>
      <div class="radio">
        <label>
<input type="radio" name="Radios_tema" id="Radios_tema" value="1">12321     </label>
      </div>
      <div class="radio">
        <label>
<input type="radio" name="Radios_tema" id="Radios_tema" value="2">новая тема 2     </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Выбор Предмета</label>
      <div class="radio">
        <label>
<input type="radio" name="Radios_pre" id="Radios_pre" value="1" \>12312           </label>
      </div>
      <div class="radio">
        <label>
<input type="radio" name="Radios_pre" id="Radios_pre" value="2" \>123123
</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group has-warning">
      <label>Заголовок страницы</label>
      <input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter ..." \>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group has-warning">
      <label>Ключевые слова</label>
      <input type="text" name="meta_k" id="meta_k" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter ...">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group has-warning">
      <label>Описание</label>
      <input type="text" name="meta_d" id="meta_d" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter ...">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Название файла 1</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter ..." \>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputFile">Загрузка файла 1</label>
      <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile" \>
      <p class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /.box-body -->
  <div class="box-footer">
    <button type="submit" name="Submit" value="Insert" class="btn btn-primary">Загрузить в базу данных
</button>
  </div>
</form>
<!-- /.box -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Потому что:

> Одновременно пользователь может выбрать лишь одну радиокнопку из
>   предложенных.

Более подробно [тут](http://,%D0%B2%D0%B7%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D1%81%20[MDN][1])(MDN) или [тут](http://htmlbook.ru/html/input/type)(htmlbook).
Используйте checkbox,они позволяют выбрать более одного варианта из предложенных.

Answer (score 0):

А вторые 3 - только 2. Потому что Вы сами задали им такие значения в атрибуте value. Если хотите, чтобы они передавали разные значения, задайте разные.

И конечно, грубейшая ошибка - использование одинаковых id. Идентификаторы должны быть уникальными. Поэтому либо сделайте их таковыми, либо вообще откажитесь от них (получать значение можно и без id):

```js
$('#sub').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   console.log($('[name="Radios_god"]:checked').val());
   console.log($('[name="Radios_tema"]:checked').val());
   console.log($('[name="Radios_pre"]:checked').val());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="box-body">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Выбор года</label>
      <div class="radio">
        <label>
<input type="radio" name="Radios_god" value="1" >2017_2018         </label>
      </div>
      <div class="radio">
        <label>
<input type="radio" name="Radios_god" value="2" >2018_2019       </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Выбор тематики</label>
      <div class="radio">
        <label>
<input type="radio" name="Radios_tema" value="3">12321     </label>
      </div>
      <div class="radio">
        <label>
<input type="radio" name="Radios_tema" value="4">новая тема 2     </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Выбор Предмета</label>
      <div class="radio">
        <label>
<input type="radio" name="Radios_pre" value="5">12312           </label>
      </div>
      <div class="radio">
        <label>
<input type="radio" name="Radios_pre" value="6">123123
</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group has-warning">
      <label>Заголовок страницы</label>
      <input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter ..." >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group has-warning">
      <label>Ключевые слова</label>
      <input type="text" name="meta_k" id="meta_k" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter ...">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group has-warning">
      <label>Описание</label>
      <input type="text" name="meta_d" id="meta_d" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter ...">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Название файла 1</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter ...">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputFile">Загрузка файла 1</label>
      <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile">
      <p class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /.box-body -->
  <div class="box-footer">
    <button id="sub" type="submit" name="Submit" value="Insert" class="btn btn-primary">Загрузить в базу данных
</button>
  </div>
</form>
<br />
```